# Error: No provider for NavParams

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am getting an error when I navigate to product page which I am using a `NavParams`. Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-product',
  templateUrl: 'product.html'
})
export class ProductPage {
  data: any;    
  constructor( public navParams: NavParams ) {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.data = this.navParams.get('item');
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? @Patrick

Comment: It's really weird. Maybe there is a module not imported in the app.module.ts or the module of the component. But I have not yet an idea. Usually NavParams should simply works by import and use. Suddenly not anymore. ... (Ionic 4)

Answer (score -3):

Go to the `AppModule` and add `NavParams` to the `providers` array.

Comment: That's pretty emphatic for something that directly contradicts the docs